# Rockmelt Browser not logging in

Tags: browser, logging, bookmarks, rockmelt

I have IE, Chrome, and Rockmelt on my pc. I use Rockmelt consistently. Up until today, I had no problems at all. Today morning, my rockmelt was logged out (which is unusual because it is always logged in.. I checked the "keep me logged in" box the first time I logged in.

I tried logging in with my facebook account, but nothing happened. It gives me the window where I am supposed to insert the details (email and password), I type them up correctly, check them a few times just to be sure, and then I hit enter. Nothing. The tab that was open before that is still there (it should have closed). I am not logged in. The Browser says that I am not logged in when I check the top-left 'rockmelt' menu.

I tried logging in with another facebook account, and I used my brother's. Rockmelt logged in, and worked fine, without any problems at all. I logged back out. I opened facebook, and logged into facebook with my account. Once I was successfully logged in, I tried to log into rockmelt (in which case it is not supposed to ask for my login details, and instead just contact facebook for them). Instead of contacting facebook however, my facebook page was 'disconnected' and an error message said I was logged out and "you need to log in to view this", and then on pressing okay, I was taken to a facebook login checkpoint.

No matter what method I try, my rockmelt will just not log in to my account.

I then tried reinstalling rockmelt without uninstalling it. Didn't work. I tried uninstalling and then downloading the latest installer and installing. Still, the exact same problem. I sent rockmelt two error reports through their "report an error" option.

After finally being able to locate my bookmarks, I copied them elsewhere, and I uninstalled rockmelt, and allowed the uninstaller to delete my userdata. The userdata folder was deleted altogether, and I could install a fresh, new, and clean rockmelt. After doing that, I tried again, but to no avail.

I believe I have ruled out all the possible causes, except for two:
first: rockmelt has my information stored online, and something happened to my information to cause the problem
second: facebook is the reason why I can't log in to rockmelt, one way or another.

I tried to rule out facebook by deactivating all the security measures, but I am not sure if the problem was in facebook that would be the solution.

I am left hanging with the two causes, unable to identify the true cause, and also unable to solve the problem by any conventional means.

I have written such a long question to make sure I do not miss any details.
I am desperate for help, for I am addicted to rockmelt.
Thank you.

Comment: Has your computer time been adjusted for DST? Only thing that has changed in the the last 24 hours that I can think of.

Comment: I haven't heard of that. I will google this now, but:
1) if you can explain a little about it
2) I live in KSA (saudia arabia, middle east) does that make any difference concerning DST ?

Comment: I looked it up. Thanks a lot for your suggestion, and sorry for my incapability of understanding, but I am not sure that is the solution to my problem. There is no DST over here. I will however change the time settings and see if anything changes. Thanks again.